# OS X dispatch_source_t hangs after a few seconds in background

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-mavericks

I have an OS X app that uses a dispatch timer to perform a task once every second.  The simplified code looks like this:

```
timerQueue2 = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myappexample_t2", nil);
    d_timer2 = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, timerQueue2);
    dispatch_source_set_timer(d_timer2, //the timer
                              dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), //the start time i guess
                              (1ull * NSEC_PER_SEC), //the interval
                              (1ull * NSEC_PER_SEC) / 1000ull); //the leeway
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(d_timer2, ^{
        NSLog(@"%f\tT2 click", CACurrentMediaTime());
    });

    dispatch_resume(d_timer2);
```

It starts out fine, logging 1 time every second, but after 10-15 seconds of using any other application, the timer will only fire once every 10 seconds.  I really have no idea what would cause this.

Here is an excerpt where the error occurs:

```
2014-08-25 18:39:10.967 JB4 App[9679:1003] 66156.545407 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:11.967 JB4 App[9679:1003] 66157.545426 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:12.967 JB4 App[9679:1003] 66158.545426 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:13.967 JB4 App[9679:1003] 66159.545425 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:14.967 JB4 App[9679:1003] 66160.545424 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:15.967 JB4 App[9679:1003] 66161.545425 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:16.967 JB4 App[9679:1003] 66162.545425 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:17.966 JB4 App[9679:1003] 66163.544404 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:18.967 JB4 App[9679:1003] 66164.545428 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:26.031 JB4 App[9679:a30b] 66171.610402 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:26.966 JB4 App[9679:a30b] 66172.545741 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:27.967 JB4 App[9679:a30b] 66173.545977 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:38.966 JB4 App[9679:a30f] 66184.545655 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:44.890 JB4 App[9679:a30f] 66190.469197 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:46.523 JB4 App[9679:a30f] 66192.102552 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:46.967 JB4 App[9679:a30f] 66192.547070 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:47.967 JB4 App[9679:a30f] 66193.547071 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:48.967 JB4 App[9679:a30f] 66194.546996 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:39:49.967 JB4 App[9679:a30f] 66195.547071 T2 click
2014-08-25 18:40:00.966 JB4 App[9679:a313] 66206.546097 T2 click
```

Update:

It seems that DISPATCH_TIMER_STRICT seems to help quite a bit with keeping the timing accurate, but now I've found something else.

To add to this, I also see nanosleep sleeping far too long sometimes.  I'm wondering if these are related somehow.

```
//milliseconds is 100
double pre = CACurrentMediaTime();
struct timespec sleepSpec;
sleepSpec.tv_sec = 0;
sleepSpec.tv_nsec = milliseconds * 1000 * 1000; //ns
nanosleep(&sleepSpec, nil);
double post = CACurrentMediaTime();
if(post-pre > .15)
    NSLog(@"Slept too long");
```

Update 2:

Is this really the best way to wait for a determined period?

```
double pre = CACurrentMediaTime();

while(CACurrentMediaTime() - pre < .1) {
    asm("NOP");
}
double post = CACurrentMediaTime();
if(post-pre > .15)
    NSLog(@"Slept too long");
```

Update 3:

I made a simple test project to see if usleep is really broken as bad as I was suspecting.  Either I'm completely misunderstanding something, or these sleep functions are useless.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
// Insert code here to initialize your application
timerQueue2 = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myappexample_t2", nil);
d_timer2 = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, DISPATCH_TIMER_STRICT, timerQueue2);
dispatch_source_set_timer(d_timer2, //the timer
                          dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), //the start time i guess
                          (1ull * NSEC_PER_SEC), //the interval
                          (1ull * NSEC_PER_SEC) / 1000ull); //the leeway
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(d_timer2, ^{
    //[self timer2Method];
    double time = CACurrentMediaTime();
    if(lastTestTime > 0 && (time - lastTestTime) > 1.1) {
        NSLog(@"Too much delay... %f", time-lastTestTime);
    }
    lastTestTime = time;
    NSLog(@"%f\tClick", lastTestTime);
});

dispatch_resume(d_timer2);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    double lastTime = -1;
    while(1) {
        double thisTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
        NSLog(@"%f", thisTime);
        if(lastTime > 0 && (thisTime-lastTime)>1.1) {
            //0.1 error range
            NSLog(@"Slept too long: %f", thisTime - lastTime);
        }
        lastTime = thisTime;
        usleep(1000000);
    }
});
```

}

And the output log.  As you can see, usleep takes a break for 11 seconds, while the asm("NOP") keeps on going just fine.  I know usleep isn't supposed to be "exact", but being 10 seconds late is unacceptable.

```
2014-08-25 20:32:14.435 TimingTest[11159:540b] 72940.352926 Click
2014-08-25 20:32:14.476 TimingTest[11159:3803] 72940.393701
2014-08-25 20:32:15.435 TimingTest[11159:540b] 72941.353001 Click
2014-08-25 20:32:15.477 TimingTest[11159:3803] 72941.395269
2014-08-25 20:32:16.435 TimingTest[11159:540b] 72942.353035 Click
2014-08-25 20:32:16.479 TimingTest[11159:3803] 72942.396839
2014-08-25 20:32:17.434 TimingTest[11159:540b] 72943.352364 Click
2014-08-25 20:32:17.479 TimingTest[11159:3803] 72943.397489
2014-08-25 20:32:18.435 TimingTest[11159:540b] 72944.353145 Click
2014-08-25 20:32:19.435 TimingTest[11159:540b] 72945.353202 Click
2014-08-25 20:32:20.435 TimingTest[11159:540b] 72946.353256 Click
2014-08-25 20:32:21.435 TimingTest[11159:540b] 72947.353306 Click
2014-08-25 20:32:22.435 TimingTest[11159:540b] 72948.353364 Click
2014-08-25 20:32:23.435 TimingTest[11159:540b] 72949.353420 Click
2014-08-25 20:32:24.435 TimingTest[11159:540b] 72950.353476 Click
2014-08-25 20:32:25.435 TimingTest[11159:540b] 72951.353530 Click
2014-08-25 20:32:26.435 TimingTest[11159:540b] 72952.353598 Click
2014-08-25 20:32:27.435 TimingTest[11159:540b] 72953.353637 Click
2014-08-25 20:32:28.435 TimingTest[11159:540b] 72954.353691 Click
2014-08-25 20:32:28.479 TimingTest[11159:3803] 72954.398038
2014-08-25 20:32:28.480 TimingTest[11159:3803] Slept too long: 11.000549
2014-08-25 20:32:29.435 TimingTest[11159:540b] 72955.353752 Click
```

Comment: Do you know if you have the same issue if you use one of GCD's global queues instead of your own?

Comment: Yes, I still have the same issue.  Also, all of the sleep functions seem to fail after repetitive use, except the asm("NOP") used above.

Comment: Looking through your console output, it appears as though the thread changes when you experience the time delay. Is that expected? Are you sure your code is not being called repeatedly?

Comment: I'm not sure why it is switching threads like that so I will investigate that soon.  For now, I made a simple test project to see how bad usleep is working for me.  The code and output is above.  "Time Click" is from my asm("NOP") sleep method and "Time" is from usleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rob pointed out above, the big issue was App Nap (which was a sneaky little thing).  Using DISPATCH_TIMER_STRICT for my dispatch timers worked, but not for general sleeping/waiting.

Here's how I fixed my horrible timer accuracy:

1) Start an activity when a serial port is opened using the proper flags for your needs.

```
self.serialActivity = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] beginActivityWithOptions:
(NSActivityLatencyCritical | 
NSActivityIdleSystemSleepDisabled | 
NSActivityAutomaticTerminationDisabled | 
NSActivitySuddenTerminationDisabled | 
NSActivityBackground) 
reason:@"Serial Port IO"];
```

2) End the activity when a serial port is closed:

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] endActivity:self.serialActivity];
```

Now my timers work even with usleep or sleepForTimeInterval.

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of App Nap. See [WWDC 2013 video Improving Power Efficiency with App Nap](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=209). The dispatch timer source example is about 30 minutes into the video.

You can tell your timer to not participate by supplying `DISPATCH_TIMER_STRICT` as the third parameter to `dispatch_source_create`, though this is obviously discouraged unless absolutely needed (e.g. interfacing with hardware that cannot tolerate timer deviation), as you lose the power savings App Nap provides.

Comment: Yes I made that change and it does help with the dispatch timing, but I've found another issue that is related to this I believe.  Answer updated in post.